# Showing blank image when uploading to AWS S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm learning how to use Amazon for storing images and have gotten to the point I can upload a file with PHP. The problem is when I upload an image it shows as a blank image like it didn't upload. Here's what I've got:

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
      'Bucket'       => $bucket,
      'Key'          => $keyname,
      'Body'   => $filepath,
      'ContentType'  => 'image/jpeg',
      'ACL'          => 'public-read',
      'StorageClass' => 'STANDARD',
      'Metadata'     => array(    
          'param1' => 'value 1',
          'param2' => 'value 2'
      )
  ));
```

Here's the image it uploaded (which doesn't help much): https://motorcyclealbum.s3.amazonaws.com/test.jpg

**Solved**

So, 'Body' needed to be 'SourceFile' if uploading an image. I'm a dork.

Comment: You're not uploading a file. You're uploading the literal text `test.jpg`. wget that url and then load the "image" into a text editor.

Comment: Huh... do you know how to upload the actual file?

Nevermind. Changed 'Body' to 'SourceFile'.

Comment: your missing: `'SourceFile'   => $filepath,`

Answer (score 1):

So, 'Body' needed to be 'SourceFile' if uploading an image. I'm a dork.